# Is it possible to generate CSR in parts? Steps till hashing on one computer and sign with privatekey somewhere else?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, csr

I am using bouncy castle libraries for generating a Certificate signing request, but instead of the keypair generator function provided by them, I am using a public key which I have generated knowing the modulus and exponent. Now I want to just hash the details and send to another server which has the private key to sign it. The private key wont leave that server.
Is it possible to do so in bouncy castle or any other libraries?
I have checked that bouncy castle hashes and signs the CSR together in on command, is it possible to separate these two commands?

[This is the public key generation with known modulus and exponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrIK3.png)

[This is the createCSR function making the csr from the user details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6TMd.png)

[This is the fun called which returns a string to the X500 principle function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muZyL.png)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The whole idea of the CSR is that it originates with the owner of the private key. That's what the digital signature is for. You should do the whole operation at the server that owns the private key.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no, at least not without hacking.

In principle it is of course possible to do this. For instance, you could simply send over a structure using `CertificationRequestInfo` :

https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/CertificationRequestInfo.java

This is basically the CSR without signature. You could then lift the signing procedure from Bouncy Castle and implement that part. However, that's not a structure that has been standardized to be used alone, so by default software won't know how to process it. *Generally the CSR is always generated where the private key is located.*

There are of course other options (or hacks):

- implement a CSR creation service at the location of the private key;
- sign the request with a temporary key, replace the public key of the CSR and re-sign the request at the location of the private key.

Of course, the problem with those options is that you would still need to do significant work at the location of the private key, which probably makes them next to useless.